# Julia DataFrame output in Jupyter error in nbconvert

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook, ijulia-notebook

The output of the DataFrame package for Julia looks good in a Jupyter notebook, but converting to a pdf with nbconvert causes the following error.

```
! Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 9474 = U+2502,
(ucs)                possibly declared in uni-37.def.
(ucs)                Type H to see if it is available with options.

See the ucs package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.410 │ Row │ A │ B       │ C    │

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.410 │ Row │ A │ B       │ C    │

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

The unicode character U+2502 is the "BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL", which is the vertical pipes the DataFrames package uses to separate the table columns.

Any suggestions on how to stop this?

Comment: I suggest you report this as an issue directly on the nbconvert repository on GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/nbconvert/templates/latex/base.tplx : \usepackage[mathletters]{ucs} % Extended unicode (utf-8) support

Comment: @ArtemOboturov, I put this template in my Jupyter directory to replace the existing base.tplx file and put it in the same folder of the notebook and nothing changed.  Sorry, but what do I do with this information?

Comment: @Clay you could build and install package from sources changing encoding from [mathletters] to something else. Or just report a bug specifying that you have unicode problems.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov, thanks.  I did this. You can see the progress on [github](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/314#issuecomment-222130808).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Thomas K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434217/thomas-k) and [minrk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938949/minrk) on [github](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/314#issuecomment-222130808) the following fixed the problem.

Setting up a config file, for example `nbConvertConfig.py`, in the same directory as the notebook that contains the following:

```
c = get_config()
c.PDFExporter.latex_command = ['xelatex', '{filename}']
```

then from the console run `jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --config nbConvertConfig.py Example.ipynb`.